# ElasticSearch 6.x / 7.x - Index design

Tags: elasticsearch

We do have a 3-node ElasticSearch Cluster 
(per Node HDD: 50TB, RAM: 128 gb, Cores: 22) with a daily document insert of 500.000.000.

The cluster is having issues with too many opened indices, Heap Size etc.
So too many shards per Node.

Since ES v6 doc types should no longer be used, instead you should use separate indices for each.
So i changed from a daily index to 9 different sub-indices with very different content sizes per day:

e.g.

```
biggest sub-Index per day: 156.9m

medium sub-index per day: 17.6m

smallest sub-index per day: 2k
```

Is it smart /best practices to split into many sub indices or does it generate to much heap impact?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

In our logging/monitoring scenario, we ingest ~30TB per day. This is what i learned inthe last years: not the document count is important, the shard size is elementary!

The perfect index size depends on the primary shard count and size. There is a sweet spot for the index size and primary shard count. How to find it? Test!

Setup a single shard index without replicas. Populate it as fast as possible (with real docs) and monitor the write/index performance. Do searches in parallel according to your SLA. The index and search times should grow lineary with the data amount added until a point where the latency will suddently grow exponentially. This is the maximum shard size for your machine/setup. 
If you don't want to test, aim for 10-40gb per shard as a rule of thumb.

So if your cluster is made of three nodes and three shards per index (as you probably want to distribute the writes across the nodes), your 'perfect' index could be around 30-120gb. If you need faster writes, add more primary shards - but don't go below 10gb per shard. Under this size, the costs for shard management and lucene overhead are bigger then the benefit of a additional shard.

Just to have it said:

- In order to prevent 64 bit pointers in the JVM you should never create instances with a heap bigger than 32gb and additional 32gb left free for lucene.
- Prevent slow (network attached) storage. Local storage is queen, SSD (or faster) is king. But using a fast fibre channel connected, SSD/NVME backed SAN should work as it does for us.

In your case, estimate how long it will take to populate the 'perfect' sized and sharded index. Then rotate in this interval. Monitor and increase/reduce the primary shard count if needed.

There are many, many, many other options in order to increase write performance, but this will be a very good starting point.

Cheers!